# MySQL & JDBC подключение к БД

Tags: jdbc

Подскажите плз. как переключиться между существующими БД. Например у меня есть 
База "первая" и база "вторая".

private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/тут намеренно не указываю к какой базе конектиться" ;

```
private static final String login = "login";

private static final String pass = "pass";
```

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, pass);

соответственно теперь нужно выбрать с какой из баз работать, как это указать? или нужно писать новый Connection и сразу выбирать необходимую базу?
Знаю что в pHp можно переключаться между базами если не ошибаюсь как-то через "select ..." или "use...".

P.S: Заранее всем большущее спасибо!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему просто не добавить в запрос имя базы данных, к таблице которой вы обращаетесь?

```
select * from db1.field;
select * from db2.field;
```

Или есть метод [setCatalog()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), пробуйте.

Вот выдержка из документации:

> If the database is not specified, the connection is made with no
>   default database. In this case, either call the setCatalog() method on
>   the Connection instance, or fully specify table names using the
>   database name (that is, SELECT dbname.tablename.colname FROM
>   dbname.tablename...) in your SQL. Opening a connection without
>   specifying the database to use is generally only useful when building
>   tools that work with multiple databases, such as GUI database
>   managers.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я только начал в этом разбираться :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать фабрику, которая будет возвращать нужный коннект.

Или на крайний случай, метод:

```
private static final String login = "login";

private static final String pass = "pass";

private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";

private static Connection getConnect(String dataBase) {
    Connection connection = null;
    String dataBaseUrl = url + dataBase;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dataBaseUrl, login, pass);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!! взял на заметку!!!